# How to get Network information from Network panel on chrome with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to achieve a specific task using Selenium and Python, but I'm running into some issues. I'm using ：
Chrome version 111.0.5563.147
Selenium 4.8.2
Python 3.11.

When I try to retrieve performance logs using "driver.get_log('performance')", I get the following error message: 'invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found.' I'm wondering if this is because the version of Chrome I'm using doesn't support performance logs or if there's something else I'm missing. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thankssss!

Here is my code:

```
def get_driver():
    
    os.popen('chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\\selenum\\AutomationProfile"')
    global driver

    caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    caps['loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.set_capability('loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","127.0.0.1:9222")
    chrome_options.set_capability("goog:chromeOptions", {"w3c": False})
    chrome_driver = "chromedriver.exe"
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=caps)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, desired_capabilities=caps, options=chrome_options)

    #print(driver.title)
    global wait
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I think this is what you are looking for***

```
network_info = driver.execute_script("var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || "
                                             "window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = "
                                             "performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;")
print(network_info)
```

Use it after intializing the driver like

```
driver = get_diver() # returns the driver object
network_info = driver.execute_script("var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || "
                                             "window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = "
                                             "performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;")
print(network_info)
```

**It will generate output like this**

```
[{'activationStart': 0, 
  'connectEnd': 17.200000017881393,
  'connectStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'decodedBodySize': 0,
  'domComplete': 296.90000000596046,
  'domContentLoadedEventEnd': 296.40000000596046,
  'domContentLoadedEventStart': 296.40000000596046,
  'domInteractive': 296.40000000596046,
  'domainLookupEnd': 17.200000017881393,
  'domainLookupStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'duration': 296.90000000596046,
  'encodedBodySize': 0,
  'entryType': 'navigation',
  'fetchStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'initiatorType': 'navigation',
  'loadEventEnd': 296.90000000596046,
  'loadEventStart': 296.90000000596046,
  'name': '',
  'nextHopProtocol': '',
  'redirectCount': 0,
  'redirectEnd': 0,
  'redirectStart': 0,
  'renderBlockingStatus': 'non-blocking',
  'requestStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'responseEnd': 103.09999999403954,
  'responseStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'responseStatus': 0,
  'secureConnectionStart': 17.200000017881393,
  'serverTiming': [],
  'startTime': 0,
  'toJSON': {},
  'transferSize': 300,
  'type': 'navigate',
  'unloadEventEnd': 0,
  'unloadEventStart': 0,
  'workerStart': 0}]
```